# Susbcribe to many promises?

Tags: angular7

I'm new to angular and I'm facing a problem where I need to call several promises and get all their results prior to continue the process.

```
// Let's assume this array is already populated
objects: any[];

// DB calls
insertObject(obj1: any): Promise<any> {
  return this.insertDB('/create.json', obj1);
}

updateObject(obj: any): Promise<any> {
  return this.updateDB('/update.json', obj);
}

// UI invokes this:
save(): void {
  this.insertObject(objects[0])
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data[0].id);
  })
  .catch((reason) => {
    console.debug("[insert] error", reason);
  });

  this.insertObject(objects[1])
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data[0].id);
  })
  .catch((reason) => {
    console.debug("[insert] error", reason);
  });

  this.updateObject(objects[1])
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data[0].status);
  })
  .catch((reason) => {
    console.debug("[update] error", reason);
  });

  //I need to catch these 3 results in order to perform the next action.

}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: if the order of execution doesn't matter use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) if order of execution matters use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using the syntax Promise.all(iterable), you can execute an array of Promises. This method resolves when all promises have resolved and fails if any of those promises fail.

[This can help you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
let firstPromise = Promise.resolve(10);
let secondPromise = Promise.resolve(5);
let thirdPromise = Promise.resolve(20);

Promise
 .all([firstPromise, secondPromise, thirdPromise])
 .then(values => {
 console.log(values);
 });
```